# Rotation background gradient xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cagradientlayer

I have a problem with my background gradient on my app. I set in `viewDidLoad` in `MainViewController`.

```
CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundGradient blackGradient];
bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
```

and every `UIViewController` extends from `MainViewController`. It works fine but after rotate device it show me only half background. Other is white. Can you help? Where can be the problem and show me it only half after rotate?[image: example]

In BackgroundGradient.m

```
@implementation BackgroundGradient
+ (CAGradientLayer*) blackGradient {

    UIColor *colorOne = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.12 green:0.13 blue:0.13 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *colorTwo = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.11 green:0.12 blue:0.13 alpha:1.0];

    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)colorOne.CGColor, colorTwo.CGColor, nil];
    NSNumber *stopOne = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    NSNumber *stopTwo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

    NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stopOne, stopTwo, nil];

    CAGradientLayer *headerLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    headerLayer.colors = colors;
    headerLayer.locations = locations;

    return headerLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your layer into controller property, than override `layoutSubviews` method and update layer frame.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.backgroundLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```